# C++ Delete "new"?

Tags: c++, pointers

Im learning about memory leak and I have a problem with how to delete "new".

I have a constructor like this:

```
Car(string nameOfCar) { carName = nameOfCar; }
```

and then I have a class that inherits Car, like this:

```
class Chrysler : public Car                             
{   
public:
    Chrysler(string sound = "wroooom") : Car(sound) {}
};
```

Okay, I have more code than that, but I dont think I need to share more code than this, to ask my question. If Im wrong, I'll give you more code, of course.

Anyway, in main, I do like this:

```
car.setCar(new Chrysler());
```

Everything works just fine, but I have a memory leak because I dont know how to delete new Chrysler(). I guess I need a destructor in Car, but I cant seem to get it right. Anyone out there willing to help me? :)

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: What does your learning material say to do? What is `car`?

Comment: The information you have given about `Car`s and `Chrysler`s constructors has no bearing whatsoever on whether `car.setCar(new Chrysler())` in `main()` causes a memory leak.    There is no such thing as a "deconstructor".

Comment: I guess you assign the allocated memory with `new Chrysler` to some member variable? Use that to free it up?

Comment: Allocate with `new`, deallocate with `delete`.

Comment: I strongly suggest a smart pointer like [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which will prevent you from needing to clean up the object yourself.

Answer (score -1):

A proper way to do this is to set delete operator inside the Destructor fucnction of every class created to avoid memory leak and crashed

Comment: `Chrysler c;` - Oops, now you'll try to call `delete` on automatic storage.